# CakePHP 3 cors,X-CSRF-Token

Tags: cakephp-3.0, csrf-protection

I have some issue with implementing CSRFProtection for my input forms.
the following variable is always empty in CSRFProtectionMiddleware.php:

```
$header = $request->getHeaderLine('X-CSRF-Token');
```

For that reason i get always CSRF 'token mismatch.'error message.
The problem would be with :

```
$this->response->cors($this->request)->allowHeaders(['X-CSRF-Token']);
```

But i dont know where should i place it because in cookbook is not clearly described here:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-cross-origin-request-headers-cors

Answer (score 0):

You can put that in your controller, but please see [this link](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#common-mistakes-with-immutable-responses).
It that page, it is described that it should be

```
$this->response = $this->response->cors($this->request)
->allowOrigin(['*.cakephp.org'])
->allowMethods(['GET', 'POST'])
->allowHeaders(['X-CSRF-Token'])
->allowCredentials()
->exposeHeaders(['Link'])
->maxAge(300)
->build();
```

rather than just

```
$this->response->cors($this->request)
->allowOrigin(['*.cakephp.org'])
->allowMethods(['GET', 'POST'])
->allowHeaders(['X-CSRF-Token'])
->allowCredentials()
->exposeHeaders(['Link'])
->maxAge(300)
->build();
```

hope it helps.